# Can XGboost algorithm be used for time series analysis?

Tags: python, r, time-series, xgboost, arima

Please find the sample dataset screenshot attached.
Here, as we can observe there is a forecast and actual data. However, we have only for about 8 years (2000- 2008) of data.

Trying: XGBoost, ARIMA

Challenges facing:
XGBoost (**Can this be used for time series analysis**? because it considers all parameters as it is not even time)
ARIMA (Not sure how to choose p,q,d for this particular dataset)

Flexible with both R/Python

Could you please suggest us which algorithm would forecast the next 8 months with considerable accuracy ?

**Am not sure if XGBoost can be even applied for time series, please share link if this is practical**

**Also, not sure Neural network such as LSTM could even work here since we have only 8 years of data on monthly level !**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> ARIMA (Not sure how to choose p,q,d for this particular dataset)

You don't need to know which p,d,q parameters you should chose.

R has the following function: 
*auto.arima* from {forecast} which can help determine the optimal p,d, q values.

Python has the following function:

*auto_arima* from pmdarima which does the same for you.

> XGboost Can this be used for time series analysis?

As for xgboost it **can** be used for timeseries data. I am not sure if it's suitable for your data (I've not yet worked with xgboost for timeseries personally) but here's some ideas on its application:
https://www.kaggle.com/furiousx7/xgboost-time-series

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Do you any personal suggestion on Algorithm for this dataset ?

Comment: i would personally first run auto.arima/auto_arima depending on your programming preference. You can follow some tutorial on the application of auto arima functions to get the gist of it, for example: for Python: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/arima-model-time-series-forecasting-python/ or https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-forecasting-with-arima-in-r-learn-data-science-tutorials for R. 
If you expect to be modelling a lot of time data, this is a great resource for R (I'm more of an R person so I have better knowledge of R sources): https://otexts.com/fpp2/